# Excel Charts, how to group categories that are similar?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, categories

I am trying to create a chart in excel that gives me statistical counts.

The table the I have is as the following:
[image]

when I am inserting a bar chart I get:
[image]

the results that I want to get is the

However, what I want to see is something like this:
[image]

I already found out some solutions changing the structure of the table such as: 
[image]
[image]

The problem is that I need also to count the number of stops per month, and changing the table doesn't help to do this second task.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing your chart, I am not sure why you are adding stops with hours.

That said, your question does not have enough detail on your needs in that request.

Here are some resources that may help.  I suggest that you use #2 below for the stops and hours as they are different data values:
1) https://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/how-to-graph-three-sets-of-data-criteria-in-an-excel-clustered-column-chart-2/
2) https://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/create-stacked-unstacked-column-chart-excel/

Comment: My goal is to create charts that count the stops (not working) of each center and the total hours of not working per month.

My problem is repeating the category "October 2018, November 2018", for every bar in the bar chart.
I need a way to group the first level of the categories (the months), without changing the table structure (like merging cells, or deleting the categories while keeping the first one) as shown in the second or third table, because changing the structure will not allow me to count the total stops for all centers during one month.
I hope I am more clear now, Thank you

Comment: I understand what you are looking for now.  You can add many groupings on the horizontal axis.  They are called Multi-Level Categories.  Check out these posts.  https://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/case-study-solution-mom-needing-help-on-science-fair-graphscharts/   and   https://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/fixing-your-excel-chart-when-the-multi-level-category-label-option-is-missing/